# Debugg ES6 Mocha tests with node-debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, mocha.js, node-inspector, babeljs

I have a ES6 Babel project set up and everything is working fine. I run my tests using Mocha. Now I want to be able to run a debugger while running tests. This is what I have done so far:

```
npm install -g node-inspector
npm install -g babel-register
```

created a file called babel-hook.js

```
require('babel/register')({
  stage: 1,
  sourceMap: 'inline',
});
```

Now in one console I run:

```
node-inspector
```

Open Chrome

Then from project root I run:

```
mocha --debug-brk test/my-test-file.js
```

Then I put a breakpoint in my test:

When I hit F8 I get the following error:

```
/Users/h/Documents/code/js/test/my-test-file.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { assert } from 'chai';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
...
```

Now what am I missing to get this working???

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the `--compilers` flag for mocha, which specifies how to compile the input files. For example, https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation gives the example

`mocha --compilers js:babel-register`

Also, try running your tests without the `--debug-brk` to help isolate whether the breakpoints are the issue, or whether it's mocha in general (the solution described here is for the latter).

Finally, if this doesn't work, you may have better results installing `babel-register` non-globally (without the `-g` flag to `npm install`) as shown in the documentation: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/